# Redirecionamento htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Eu tenho o seguinte redirecionamento:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)\/([^/]*) http://ip/~user/codigo.php?nome=$1&numero=$2
```

Para gerar a url:

> http://www.site.com.br/stackoverflow/123456

Mas existem outras pastas, como por ex: assets/css/main.css e outras como /css/nome/outro.css e estas estão sendo redirecionadas para:

> Ex: http://www.site.com.br/codigo.php?nome=assets/css&numero=main.css

Como resolver o problema?

Tentei algo como:

```
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ http://www.site.com.br/assets/$
```

**Observação:** existem outras pastas, além do exemplo assets e algumas delas possuem subpastas e outras não, ou seja, não existe um padrão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui uma solução para o meu problema.

Adicionei o seguinte:

```
RewriteRule ^(assets|css|images|js|fonts) - [L]
```

Antes do redirecionamento:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)\/([^/]*) http://ip/~user/codigo.php?nome=$1&numero=$2
```

E funcionou perfeitamente.

Para quem estiver com o mesmo problema, esta é a solução.